# arguments of main?

Tags: c, arguments, program-entry-point

I know that the signature of main is:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv);
```

But I really don't know why main like this will work too:

```
main(a){}
```

what's 'a' doing here? why the compiler don't show error?? Because I havn't declare 'a' before I use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a feature of older C code called "implicit int". Any variable whose type is not specified is assumed to be an `int`. Similarly, any function whose return type is not specified is assumed to return an `int`. It's now considered *deprecated*, but becomes useful in obfuscated code and [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3290/2381).

So you should read it as

```
int main(int a) {}
```

where the `int`s have been omitted because they are *implicit.*

As WhozCraig mentions, from a Standards point-of-view this is *not conforming* and *not portable*. But pragmatically, a lot of compilers will let you get away with this when not in standards-conformance mode.

Implicit `int` behavior doesn't get you out of declaring variables, however.

```
main(a){
    b,c; // int declarations
    c = 5;
    b = c + 10;
    d = b; // No! d is not declared for you, even with implicit int happening.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 on the analysis. That it is accepted as a valid `main()` is an implementation-defined issue. It does not conform to either of the stated required allowances per C99 §5.1.2.2.1, namely `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. The third option listed in the standard, "or in some other implementation-defined manner." would therefore be the only allowable alternative.